# Inserting Array of Objects into Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im trying to store documents containing data about films into my DB.

I am getting the data from an API in JSON format.

```
{"Title":"Black Panther","Year":"2018","Rated":"PG-13","Released":"16 Feb 2018","Runtime":"134 min","Genre":"Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi","Director":"Ryan Coogler","Writer":"Ryan Coogler, Joe Robert Cole, Stan Lee (based on the Marvel Comics by), Jack Kirby (based on the Marvel Comics by)","Actors":"Chadwick Boseman, Michael B. Jordan, Lupita Nyong'o, Danai Gurira","Plot":"T'Challa, the King of Wakanda, rises to the throne in the isolated, technologically advanced African nation, but his claim is challenged by a vengeful outsider who was a childhood victim of T'Challa's father's mistake.","Language":"Swahili, Nama, English, Xhosa, Korean","Country":"USA","Awards":"14 nominations.","Poster":"https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg1MTY2MjYzNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTc4NTMwNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg","Ratings":[{"Source":"Internet Movie Database","Value":"7.7/10"},{"Source":"Rotten Tomatoes","Value":"97%"},{"Source":"Metacritic","Value":"88/100"}],"Metascore":"88","imdbRating":"7.7","imdbVotes":"247,680","imdbID":"tt1825683","Type":"movie","DVD":"15 May 2018","BoxOffice":"$501,105,037","Production":"Marvel Studios","Website":"https://www.facebook.com/BlackPantherMovie/","Response":"True"}
```

Having this data I can access all the fields except for the ratings filed which is an array

```
exports.addFilm = function (req, res) {
console.log(req.body);

data = req.body;

var film = new Film({
   title: data.Title,
   year: data.Year,
   rated: data.Rated,
   released: data.Released,
   runtime: data.Runtime,
   genre: data.Genre.split(","),
   director: data.Director,
   writer: data.Writer.split(","),
   actors: data.Actors.split(","),
   plot: data.Plot,
   language: data.Language.split(","),
   country: data.Country,
   poster: data.Poster,
   ratings: data.Ratings,
   imbdID: data.imdbID,
   production: data.Production,
   website: data.Website,
});

film.save(function (err, results) {
    console.log(results._id);
    res.json(results);
});

}
```

In the code everyting works except for the data.Ratings which evaluates to undefined. How can I store the three elements in Ratings in my DB?

Comment: ratings: [{
            Source: String,
            Value: String,
        }] ,

Comment: Thats the rating part

Comment: Looks like you might be sending as `application-x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`. The array should parse fine with `application/json`.